# Validating Observable Array, using Knockout.Validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

We are building a Single Page Application using Knockout, Durandal & Breeze.

We have a observable array, & want to validate whether it contains any value or not i.e. the text box accepting values has been provided with any value or not. I am trying to achieve this using Knockout.Validation plugin.

Code for view model is-

```
withs = ko.observableArray([]).extend({ required: true }),
```

and HTML is

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
   <select multiple="true" 
        data-bind="options: entities, optionsValue: 'Id', optionsText: 'Name', 
                   selectedOptions: withs, select2: {}" 
        style="width: 249px; border-radius: 4px;"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom validator like:

```
ko.validation.rules['arrayMustContainAtLeastOne'] = {
    validator: function (val, required) {
        if (required) {
            if (val.length > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
    message: 'Require at least one item in list'
}
```

Would double check the docs to see if this is included first though

Comment: I tried using above code suggested by you, but it is not working for select2 input which is nothing but multiselect textarea. The message is not displayed even if the user input is null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach.

```
ko.validation.rules['minArrayLength'] = {
    validator: function (obj, params) {
        return obj.length >= params.minLength;
    },
    message: "Array does not meet minimum length requirements"
};

//Must call registerExtenders() or there will be no validation.
//It won't throw any errors either, it will just be ignored
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

//if you use this commented binding, the minLength will not come through correctly
//ko.observableArray([]).extend({ minArrayLength: { minLength: 1, message: 'Must select at least one item'} });
ko.observableArray([]).extend({ minArrayLength: { params: { minLength: 1 }, message: 'Must specify at least one unit per part number' } });
```

Thewad's solution is certainly valid, but if you don't have a call to registerExtenders() after your custom validation rule it could explain why the validation wasn't working for you.

Comment: Hi @Tobin, the answer should work if it's changed to 

      ko.validation.rules.minArrayLength = {
            validator: function (obj, otherVal) {
                return obj.length >= otherVal.minLength;
            },
            message: "Array does not meet minimum length requirements"
        };

Comment: I made a correction, although I'm not sure if it's exactly what you meant. The most important part I found is that the parameters passed to the validator have to be wrapped in brackets or else the value just comes through as "true", which is very strange to me... The reason my code was working for me is because a boolean "true" is interpreted as an integer 1, which just so happens to be the minLength value that I was using.

Comment: This solution is not working for me. I have a `ViewModel` with an observable array named Codes of type Code. The Code class/model has a code property which is a `KnockoutObservable<string>`. When the app is running, for each Code that is present in the Codes array, input fields are output in the View with `textInput` data-binding, and I wanted to have validation for min/max length for each code so the right error shows. It is not working and I do not get any console errors. Any suggestions?